# Monitor system usage to fix power consumption issues

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, battery

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04, and I want to do some system profiling. My main goals are to improve startup speed and power usage. What instruments can I use to profile daemons/processes to get the time they took on system startup or see their usage of CPU during normal operation? It would also be great if I had some tools to monitor disk/network usage, since these operations are pretty battery-hungry too.

Comment: I've looked at powertop, but it can't record power stats, so it is basically useless.

Comment: If it works with your processor, then turbostat (linux tools-common package, i think) is a good tool for monitoring processor package power. I always have this command running, `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`

Comment: @DougSmythies looks like it won't work for me: `WARNING: turbostat not found for kernel 5.3.0-28`

Comment: If you are not running the default kernel, then this might be an issue, yes. It should not be an issue, as upstream has committed that turbostat will not be kernel version dependent. There is an [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1844201) about this, if anyone is interested. Meanwhile you can use turbostat by bypassing the Ubuntu dependency wrapper and running it directly (which I do not know how, because I use a different method).

Comment: Strange thing is that I'm actually running default kernel, one which came with the OS itself. I guess I'll just try running it directly

Comment: If your system is up to date and linux-tools-common is up to date, then turbostat should work. But I only use the upstream of version turbostat and am not the expert here. Readers should add an "effects me too" to [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1844201), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your boot performance, see `systemd-analyze`.

Your network chip likely uses a lot less power than your display.

From my recent experience with Kubuntu 19.10, a good deal of power is wasted by the external GPU. If you have a system with both an integrated Intel GPU and an external NVidia GPU, there are ways to activate the NVidia chip only when needed (google for "optimus").

Comment: I've already dealt with GPU using NVIDIA PRIME, thanks! I'll see what I can get with systemd-analyze.